# Flickity gallery: Style so clicking anywhere on the image advances to next?

Tags: css, flickity

I am trying to get the following behavior in my Flickity gallery:

Click anywhere on the entire image, and it advances to the next image.

I am finding that resizing (+hiding) the buttons isn't behaving as expected. Can anybody suggest a better approach? Website built using Semplice, the CSS I'm using is:

```css
.flickity-prev-next-button.next {  
     width:100%; 
     height:100%;
     opacity:0; 
}
```

The corners of the image are draggable but not clickable when I style it this way. Weirder to me, the clickable region is shaped like a diamond.

I want the entire image to be clickable to advance the gallery. I'd be grateful for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by defining a border-radius and background color for the Flickity control button.

My layperson's thought is that default background transparency in the button was affecting its shape. Only the "arrow" part had a color, the background was transparent, so the shape got defined by this into a diamond shape and that's why I had a "diamond" inside of the image that was clickable.

Once a border-radius and background color were added, the dimensions of the button were fully rectangular instead of the diamond shape of the arrow control.

```css
.flickity-prev-next-button.next {  
   width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background: #333;
     border-radius:15px;
     opacity:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some more default styling you need to overwrite:

```js
.flickity-prev-next-button.next {  
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  opacity:0; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  transform: none;
}
```

Should do it

Edit: also your header makes it so you can't click images behind it. Personally I'd fix that by just making the header white.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am still finding issues with the size/positioning of the button. Top:0; with Right:0; move the middle of the button (not the top of the button) to the top of the box, thus moving the control partially outside the image.   Fixing the default styling does seem like the path I need though

Comment: That transform:none is important. You have a transform -50% that's why it's going outside the image